# What would the index be for the square root on n?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-complexity

Given the definition
$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c
$$
I need to know what the value of *c* is for $\sqrt{n}$.

I don't know how it works with the square root of values, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$x^2=y\iff x=y^{1/2}.$$